# Shuffle algorithm on generic array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, generics, junit

I've tried to understand how generics works. I created several implementations sorting algorithms and before sorting i shuffling input array by **shuffleArray** method in AbstractSorter.java:

```
public class AbstractSorter<T extends Comparable> {

public void swap(final T[] input, int srcPos, int dstPos) {
    if (dstPos != srcPos) {
        T accum = input[dstPos];
        input[dstPos] = input[srcPos];
        input[srcPos] = accum;

    }
}

public T[] shuffleArray(final T[] inputArray) {
    //        E[] arr = (E[])new Object[INITIAL_ARRAY_LENGTH];
    T[] result = (T[]) new Comparable[inputArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(inputArray, 0, result, 0, inputArray.length);
    int index;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = result.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        if (index != i) {
            swap(result, i, index);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean more(final T x, final T y) {
    return (x.compareTo(y) > 0);
}
```

but when i try to use like this:

```
AbstractSorter<Integer> sortHelper = new AbstractSorter();
Integer[] expResult = new Integer[]{-30, -29, -28, -27 };
Integer[] shuffleArray = sortHelper.shuffleArray(expResult);
System.out.println("Array ="+Arrays.toString(shuffleArray));
```

it i got exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
[Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
```

I don't understand how can i fix shuffle method. Is it possible implement this functionality on arrays or should i migrate to collections?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is wrong with the inbuilt Shuffle method why not use that ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `T extends Comparable<T>`?

Comment: @StackFlowed i use arrays and would'n like to migrate to list. But if there is no other way i will.

Comment: And `T[] result = (T[]) inputArray.clone();` will resolve the other problem I think.

Comment: @JohnBl you can just do `Arrays.asList(yourValues)` to convert to list.

Comment: @maraca sorry i don't understand where i should put it. could you share an example on gist?

Comment: @JohnBl first line in `shuffleArray` (not counting the comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the exception is because you're trying to convert an array of `Comparable` objects to an array of `Integer` objects, which is illegal. You can only cast from `Integer` to `Comparable`, not the other way around.

This is your problem: `T[] result = (T[]) new Comparable[inputArray.length];`. Here you're casting a `Comparable` to `T` which is an `Integer` in this case.

Change the lines `T[] result = (T[]) new Comparable[inputArray.length];` and `System.arraycopy(inputArray, 0, result, 0, inputArray.length);` to `T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);` so your `shuffleArray` method looks like:

```
public T[] shuffleArray(final T[] inputArray) {
    T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(inputArray, inputArray.length);
    int index;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = result.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        if (index != i) {
            swap(result, i, index);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Running the example with:

```
AbstractSorter<Integer> sortHelper = new AbstractSorter();
Integer[] expResult = new Integer[]{-30, -29, -28, -27};
Integer[] shuffleArray = sortHelper.shuffleArray(expResult);

System.out.println ("Array =" + Arrays.toString(shuffleArray));
```

Produces the result: `Array =[-30, -28, -29, -27]`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create an array of `Comparable`, but the expected array is an  array of `Integer`.

You can't cast an array of something to an array of something else, even though the contained objects are parents .

But as you said, we can't easily create an array of generic objects, so I refered to [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Replace :

```
T[] result = (T[]) new Comparable[inputArray.length];
```

with :

```
final T t = inputArray[0];
T[] result = (T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass(), inputArray.length);
```

Comment: sorry, but i can't compile my class at all - Generic array creation

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want the following:

```
public class AbstractSorter<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

and

```
T[] result = (T[]) new Comparable<T>[inputArray.length];
```

and

```
AbstractSorter<Integer> sortHelper = new AbstractSorter<>();
```